# How to measure similarity score between one row and matrix/table in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, dot-product

I have user's preference table:

```
+-------+---- -+-------+-------+--
|user_id|Action| Comedy|Fantasy|
+-------+----- +-------+-------+--
|   100 |  0   | 0.33..| 0.66..|
|   101 |0.42..| 0.15..| 0.57..|
+-------+------+-------+-------+--
```

And movies genre content table:

```
+-------+---- -+-------+-------+--
|movieId|Action| Comedy|Fantasy|
+-------+----- +-------+-------+--
|  1001 |  1   |   1   |   0   |
|  1011 |  0   |   1   |   1   |
+-------+------+-------+-------+--
```

How to take dot product (similarity distance) of user's preference row (by his `user_id`) and each movie content row in order to output most preferential `movieId` by movie's genre? Either in RDD or DataFrame format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try.

The `crossProduct` merge the dataframes with the `movieId` for each `user_id`, so it will create the size of `# of user_id * # of movieId` dataframe.

Then, you can multiply for each element of the arrays by `zip_with` with a specific function. In this case, `x * y` for each `x` element of `array1` and `y` element of `array2`.

Finally, you can `aggregate` the multiplication result of the array, that is just a sum. Staring from `sum = 0`, add the `x` element of the `zipArray` to the temp variable `sum` which is exactly the usual summation function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, arrays_zip, expr, rank, desc

df1 = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("test1.csv")
df2 = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("test2.csv")

df1_cols = df1.columns
df1_cols.remove('user_id')
df2_cols = df2.columns
df2_cols.remove('movieId')


df1 = df1.withColumn('array1', array(df1_cols))
df2 = df2.withColumn('array2', array(df2_cols))

df3 = df1.crossJoin(df2)
df3.show(10, False)

+-------+------+------+-------+------------------+-------+------+------+-------+---------+
|user_id|Action|Comedy|Fantasy|array1            |movieId|Action|Comedy|Fantasy|array2   |
+-------+------+------+-------+------------------+-------+------+------+-------+---------+
|100    |0.0   |0.33  |0.66   |[0.0, 0.33, 0.66] |1001   |1     |1     |0      |[1, 1, 0]|
|100    |0.0   |0.33  |0.66   |[0.0, 0.33, 0.66] |1011   |0     |1     |1      |[0, 1, 1]|
|101    |0.42  |0.15  |0.57   |[0.42, 0.15, 0.57]|1001   |1     |1     |0      |[1, 1, 0]|
|101    |0.42  |0.15  |0.57   |[0.42, 0.15, 0.57]|1011   |0     |1     |1      |[0, 1, 1]|
+-------+------+------+-------+------------------+-------+------+------+-------+---------+


df3 = df3.withColumn('zipArray',   expr("zip_with(array1, array2, (x, y) -> x * y)")) \
         .withColumn('dotProduct', expr("aggregate(zipArray, 0D, (sum, x) -> sum + x)"))
                     
df3.show(10, False)

+-------+------+------+-------+------------------+-------+------+------+-------+---------+-----------------+----------+
|user_id|Action|Comedy|Fantasy|array1            |movieId|Action|Comedy|Fantasy|array2   |zipArray         |dotProduct|
+-------+------+------+-------+------------------+-------+------+------+-------+---------+-----------------+----------+
|100    |0.0   |0.33  |0.66   |[0.0, 0.33, 0.66] |1001   |1     |1     |0      |[1, 1, 0]|[0.0, 0.33, 0.0] |0.33      |
|100    |0.0   |0.33  |0.66   |[0.0, 0.33, 0.66] |1011   |0     |1     |1      |[0, 1, 1]|[0.0, 0.33, 0.66]|0.99      |
|101    |0.42  |0.15  |0.57   |[0.42, 0.15, 0.57]|1001   |1     |1     |0      |[1, 1, 0]|[0.42, 0.15, 0.0]|0.57      |
|101    |0.42  |0.15  |0.57   |[0.42, 0.15, 0.57]|1011   |0     |1     |1      |[0, 1, 1]|[0.0, 0.15, 0.57]|0.72      |
+-------+------+------+-------+------------------+-------+------+------+-------+---------+-----------------+----------+


from pyspark.sql import Window

window = Window.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy(desc('dotProduct'))

df3.select('user_id', 'movieId', 'dotProduct') \
   .withColumn('rank', rank().over(window)) \
   .filter('rank = 1') \
   .drop('rank') \
   .show(10, False)

+-------+-------+----------+
|user_id|movieId|dotProduct|
+-------+-------+----------+
|101    |1011   |0.72      |
|100    |1011   |0.99      |
+-------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you, sir, it worked perfectly! Although, its quite difficult for me to understand this line `df3 = df1.crossJoin(df2).withColumn('dotProduct',  expr("aggregate(zip_with(array1, array2, (x, y) -> x * y), 0D, (sum, x) -> sum + x)"))` , could you please kindly explain what exactly is going on here?

Comment: I recommend you to find the function definition, anyway I added some notes.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, its both clear and precise!

Comment: What part of code I should change in order to take only a given row from df1 by its id number and compute dot product with rows from df2?

Comment: when load the csv to the `df1` and then asap filter the `user_id`

Comment: thank you, do you know how to compute cosine similarity instead of dot product?

Comment: well, maybe from wikipedia? Post another question for showing this to many others

Comment: sorry I am using spark 1.6 so trying to write the same using udf without aggregate and zip_with functions, but facing some error, please if you can look at it, any reviewing highly appreciated [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63644536/typeerror-while-manipulating-arrays-in-pyspark)